# Comparing string dates html

Tags: javascript, html, string, date

I want to extract this date and compare it with another one:

```
<table id="table">
    <tbody>
        <tr><th>Date</th><td>05/12/2016</td></tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Maybe something like this:

```
var date = document.getElementById("table").children[0].children[1].innerHTML;
var new_date = 06/12/2016;
if (date < new_date) ...
```

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var date = new Date(document.querySelector('#table tbody tr > td').textContent);
var new_date = new Date('06/12/2016');

if (date < new_date) {
  console.log('date is less than new_date'); 
}
```

```html
<table id="table">
  <tbody>
    <tr><th>Date</th><td>05/12/2016</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Update:**

To get today's date in `MM/DD/YYYY` format do the following:

```js
var date = new Date();
var formattedDate = `${date.getMonth() + 1}/${date.getDate()}/${date.getFullYear()}`;

console.log(formattedDate);
```

Comment: No need for the ``getTime``, date objects are comparable

Comment: Thanks roger. I'll revise.

Comment: Thanks! And how could I get today's date in that format (MM/DD/YYYY)?

Comment: See my updated answer.

Comment: I've seen. Thanks! But I have a doubt about that 1 after getMonth()... What does it mean?

Comment: It's because Javascript's Date API has an obscure quirk where the first month of the year is referenced as `0`. Therefore we need to add `1` to, *normalize* it.

Comment: Parsing date strings with the Date constructor is strongly recommended against. It certainly makes no sense to parse the string to create a different string to then parse with Date.

Comment: @CarlEdwards—that is not "an obscure quirk". Javascript's Date is modelled on Java's Date and has had zero indexed months for over 20 years.

Comment: Maybe phrasing it as an *obscure quirk* was a lack of a better word but as far as parsing the string, this is what the OP requested. Basing your downvote on this notion alone sounds a little ridiculous to me.

Comment: @CarlEdwards—I provided a reason for the down vote, it's not about the comment.